# Moving objects according to touchesMoved

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, touches, touchesmoved

So I'm trying to move an object using the touches moved function, however I'm not sure how to do that when the coordinates are not predetermined. This is what I've got going :

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()
    var point = touch?.locationInView(self.view)
}
```

So basically I'm making the `point` variable the coordinates (points).
Then what needs to happen is that i move an object (in this case `Label1`) to that location:

```
func MoveObject(point) {
    Label1.frame.origin = ( /* Here would the ´point´ be */ )
}
```

Also keep in mind that later when this problem is out of the way I'm going to change the location so its not where you touch but it moves accordingly. I don't know if that matters really but I'm just saying in case it does ;)

Comment: So, what is the problem? You already have `locationInView` - get it from the moving view's parent view and simply set, e.g., the center of the moving view to that point?

Comment: I need to know how to use the `locationInView`, the `point`, in order to have it move the label. @Arkku

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()
    var point = touch?.locationInView(self.view)
    moveObject(point)
}
...
func MoveObject(point) {
    Label1.center = point
}
```